# WSO2 - How to return to service provider page

Tags: java, authentication, wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have an authenticator based on ldap and I am not using any custom login page. I receive the certificate in the header. But then when I checked the user how can I return to the original website?

[image]

Comment: Can we assume the SP initiates the authentication? OAuth2/SAML? Did you specify the redirect uri (for OAuth2)  or ACS URL (for saml)?

Comment: SAML.. how do you mean specify the redirect uri? How?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you have a problem with. You could extend the question to fill your scenario and SAML SP parameters. After successful authentication the user should be posted or redirected to defined ACS (asserion consumer) URL of the SP. If that doesn't  happen, something is wrongly configured

Comment: I see that in other example they put a .war under webapps. I didnt do that. What is it?

Comment: it's a sample service provider.. apparently you have one already (based on Shibboleth).  You have the AssertionConsumerURL set, so - do you have any errors in the logs? BTW: in SAML always enable response signing - response or claims must be signed (that may not solve your issue, but it is necessary for security)

Comment: no errors in the logs, it just stays on localhost:9443/... and doesnt go back to http://sp01..

Comment: why do they call the servlet in initiateAuthenticationRequest